# What is the difference between Middleware vs Guards vs Gates/Policies in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, authorization

Can anyone help me with understanding when/how to use each of these?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I wondered about this as well, and after some reading, here's what I've concluded:

### Middleware

Typically **runs on a route** (but you can also run it on controller methods) and can be **used to filter or inspect incoming requests**.

One example would be `auth`, which determines if the person trying to request a particular route is authenticated (logged in) to the system. Another example would be to check that a request has a specific header (e.g. if you want to check that the app is sending a `X-MYAPP-CUSTOMHEADER` header or something)

As mentioned, middleware can be defined on a route (e.g. in `web.php` or `api.php`) or in a controller.

An example in web.php:

```php
// Get all the posts, but only if the user has signed in to the website 
Route::get('/posts', [PostController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth');
```

An example in `PostController.php`:

```php
public function __construct() {
    // Apply the `auth` middleware to every function in this controller
    $this->middleware('auth');
    // Apply the `signed` middleware, but only to the functions `download` and `delete`
    $this->middleware('signed', ['only' => ['download', 'delete']]);
}
```

### Gates

Gates are functions defined in your `AuthServiceProvider.php` file (in the `App\Providers` folder) and **specify what a user is allowed to do and what they're not allowed to do**. For example:

```php
Gate::define('delete-post', function (User $user, Post $post) {
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
});
```

Then in your `PostController`'s `delete` method:

```php
public function delete(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    if (Gate::denies('delete-post', $post)) { // Returns true if `$post->user_id` is not the same as `$user->id` (a.k.a the user is not allowed to delete this post)
        abort(403);
    }

    $post->delete();
}
```

You can also use some helper methods in your blade templates:

```php
@can('delete-post', $post)
    <!-- Show a link to the delete page here -->
@endcan
```

(I've expanded on this below)

### Guards

Guards are a way to specify **how users are authenticated for requests**.

In a project I'm working on, I have a `jwt` (JSON Web Token) guard on my API routes. This means that when I do something like `auth()->attempt(['username' => 'test', 'password' => 'test']);`, the `auth()` function will try and authenticate me using the `jwt` guard.

Which guard to use is specified in `auth.php`. Mine currently looks like this:

```php
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users'
        ],
    ],
```

So in this case, requests coming in via the browser will have a session assigned when they log in, and requests coming in via an API call will need to get / provide a token to authenticate. Both will look up the `users` table to check the username / password when authenticating.

You can specify which guard to use with the `auth()` call:

`auth('api')->attempt(['api_key' => 'abc1234'])`

(and side note, I got caught up with this, as I was wondering why `auth()->user()` wasn't returning the current user, and that's because `web` was the default guard, and I was trying to get the user who had authenticated via `api`, so be sure to be explicit about which guard!)

### Policies

Policies work similarly to gates, but just **apply to a specific model and are stored in their own file** (in `App\Policies`)

You can create one by using `php artisan make:policy PostPolicy -m Post`. It'll create a file called `PostPolicy.php` which will create a bunch of functions:

```php
viewAny // Can the user even look at this model? If no, they'll be denied for all the below methods
view // Can the user look at the specified Post?
create // Can they create a new Post
update // Can they edit / update the specified Post?
delete // Can they (soft) delete the specified Post?
restore // Can they restore the specified (soft) deleted Post?
forceDelete // Can they force delete the specified Post?
```

Typical function(s) would look like this:

```php
public function viewAny(User $user)
{
    // If this returns true, then the other methods will be evaluated.
    return $user->can_view_posts;
}

public function forceDelete(User $user, Post $post)
{
    // If this returns true, then the user can force delete the post.
    // This depends on viewAny being true
    return $post->user_id == $user->id;
}
```

One thing to note, is that `viewAny` is NOT the same as "view all"! Think of `viewAny` as the front door to a building. If `viewAny` is true, you can go into the lobby, but you can't look inside any of the rooms unless `view` for a particular room is also true.

I believe you can also use the `@can` in blade templates with policies:

```php
@can('forceDelete', $post)
    <!-- Show button to force delete a post here -->
@endcan
```

And the inverse too:

```php
@cannot('view', $post)
    <!-- Show a greyed out button or something -->
@cannot
```

As well as the `@canany` for checking multiple permissions:

```php
@canany(['edit', 'delete'])
    <!-- Show something if the user can edit OR delete -->
@endcanany
```

### Conclusion

I hope this has been useful. I certainly learned a lot while reading up on this. There's way more to this than I thought, so it's worth checking out the Laravel documentation because I may be right in some things, but I may be waaay off in other things.

Answer (score 3):

**Gate** is use to add logic for login user access

but **Policies**  is use for add logic in model access level

#### Example of gate

```php
Gate::define('update-post', function (User $user, Post $post) {
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#writing-gates

here you can see in gate your gettin `$user` as callback so it for user access gate

#### Example of policies

run
`php artisan make:policy PostPolicy --model=Post`

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\User;

class PostPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine if the given post can be updated by the user.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#generating-policies

here you can see `PostPolicy` is getting 2 parameter `$user` and `$post` which is model level access

Answer (score -3):

**Gate used to add logic for login user access**
**Policies used to add logic in model access level**

Comment: This is word-for-word identical to the first two lines of the other answer, but without the benefit of punctuation, whitespace or any further explanation. Why bother?